# Git - rebasing to a particular tag

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-tag

*(This seems like it should be very easy to do, yet I'm coming up empty on searches so far.)*

I have a body of code from an upstream source, with various versions tagged in it on various branches.

I am working on my "develop" branch which was based on tag "v1.0". many versions have come out since then, but while "v2.0" is interesting, I want to rebase my develop branch to "v1.5" and continue working there (assume I don't plan to feed that back upstream). Maybe later I'll rebase it again to "v2.0".

(For this purpose assume "v1.x"s are all tags on the same branch. For extra credit we can assume "v2.0" is a tag on another branch.)

I was able to create the initial "develop" branch based on the "v1.0" tag easily enough, but rebase appears to only work with branches. Can't one rebase using tags as well? If not, what's the right way to accomplish that (so as to have exactly the same effect as rebasing to a particular tag)?

Comment: You can rebase _to_ a tag. If you can't do that, please include the command you used.

Comment: Hmm! I was doing this with TortoiseGit (which flat out doesn't offer the option of rebasing with tags - or does it?) and then I tried it in git bash and it had no effect... but I apparently had a syntax error (I tried "git rebase develop v1.5" which was incorrect... I just used "git rebase v1.5" with develop checked out and it appears to have worked). Edit: Actually, I did that for a reason, which was a not-quite-good example I found elsewhere.

Comment: I think checkout and rebase is the standard way to do this.

Comment: Yes, either separately or as Karl describes below, both in one step. I'm surprised TortoiseGit didn't offer that ability... it led me to wonder if it was possible at all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You would use the following command:

```
git rebase --onto v1.5 v1.0 develop
```

The `develop` part of the command must be a branch, but the other two can be whatever you want.

Comment: Looks like I screwed up the syntax originally, thus leading to my question. And the apparently absence of this functionality in tortoisegit's rebase option led me to question if it was even possible. However, this thread has proven to be more informative than I expected. Thanks!

Comment: Followup: I've tried this going back and forth and back again. This actually proved less complicated than my original test merge branch-to-branch using TortoiseGit (which, because the ancestor tag couldn't be specified, was throwing needless merge "conflicts" which could've been automatically resolved with the added info just like the command-line git does. It's still handy software, but apparently it doesn't handle rebases as thoroughly as it could.

Comment: in v2.29 the `develop` part doesn't have to be a branch, but if it isn't a branch (e.g. tag or hash) you'd be left in a detached HEAD, which has its own dangers.