# git rebase --onto still ends up with the code I'm trying to eliminate - can't see where my mistake is

Tags: git, rebase

I have some production code that had to be rolled back, because testing that I was told was completed successfully was not done. It was put into production, committed to the master branch, and then was "rolled back" when users discovered the untested bugs.

Note that I normally am the only one writing to this repo, but some changes were done to it while I was on vacation, and I'll admit I've gotten somewhat confused.

In any case, I'm pretty sure I want to rebase my new code against the older, pre-bug, "rolled-back" version of the code, which I believe should be done using `git rebase --onto`

Several articles have helped me to learn at least something about this (clearly I still have much to learn). The diagramming format you see here is inspired by the more helpful articles I've read.

So, I have the following commits:

```
    A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---I
```

The errors were introduced in the production code from B to E, and I wrote F through I based on this code. So:

```
    Known good
    |   Buggy and to discard
    |   |               Good and needs to be replayed onto A
    |   |               |
    >   ->              ->
    A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---I
```

So that I end up with:

```
    A---F---G---H---I
```

Now from all the reading I've done, what I think I'm supposed to run is: `git rebase --onto A F I`

But when I do that the code I end up with still has all the bad code in it.

So, I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot see what it is.

I have read the following already (which were helpful, but didn't seem to describe my situation precisely) https://medium.com/@gabriellamedas/git-rebase-and-git-rebase-onto-a6a3f83f9cce [Git - rebasing to a particular tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469855/git-rebasing-to-a-particular-tag) https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Maybe I'm doing this all wrong. I want to rewind to the state that production is currently in (the "rolled back" state), and then replay the development I've done onto that. Perhaps there's a better way.

Any and all help, advice, tips, criticisms, places to read more about this, etc., would be very gratefully accepted.

Comment: One thing I always find helpful is including the `-i` (`--interactive`) option to `git rebase`, so that I get a list of the commits it thinks need to be rebased. If you do that, do you see the list you expect?

Comment: I agree. What if you just rebase interactively from A and `drop` B, C, D, and E?

Comment: If that doesn't "work" then you may be mistaken about where the "bad" code was introduced.

Comment: Why is it required to remove the bad commits from history? The changes were already reverted (I assume in commit `E`?) and your current master files are in a good state. Having the bad commits does not hurt.

Comment: So when I rebase interactively, the doc that comes up shows each of the commits `I` want to include (`F` through `I` in my example), and none of the commits I don't want. Also, the code I don't want is already present in commit `F`, but is not in commit `A`, so that all looks the way I would expect based on my current understanding.
One thing that's confusing to me is that if I run the rebase command with `--into A F I` it means everything `B` through `E` is dropped, but some of what I read was a bit unclear, and possibly suggested that in fact `E` through `I` would be retained.

Comment: Regarding keeping the bad commits, I have no problem with that, I just have no clue how I would go about slicing and dicing the newer commits and attaching them to the older stuff. That's simply a lack of git skills on my part. I wouldn't even know what that's called, so I don't know how I'd search for it (I'm happy to google and RTFM if I know what I'm searching for). Is that some kind of funky backward merge or something?

Comment: If `F` contains the bad code then you _must not_ include F in your final history (but you write that you expect to have `A-F-G-H-I`. You want `A-G-H-I` instead – _without_ the bad commit. Why do you need to "attach to the old stuff"? The bad commit was already reverted, so you have the working code back. You don't need to attach anything to anywhere, just keep working on the reverted, now-good code. If you want to only keep A and everything after the revert (`E`?), then `git rebase --onto A F I`.

Comment: So I figured I'd see if I could figure how how to extract and apply a diff. I was able to extract the diff, but on apply I got the error "patch does not apply", which is another interesting rabbit hole.
Learning lots about git today!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've certainly learned a few things about git, so that's good.

I could not ultimately make any sense out of this, because what all the documentation and responses said, and what I was experiencing, did not match.

I accept full responsibility for this, but in the interest of time, what I did was to diff all the commits from `F` to `I` against `A`, and then manually add those to `A`.

Then I had the bright idea to use GitLab because it has a nice interface for merges and diffs, and did a compare of my `A-F-I` code against `B-E`, and that was looking good.

So, I forged `A-F-I` into a new branch, and requested a merge of `B-E` into it.

Some conflicts, but really nothing too tricky. More importantly, the code all looked the way I would expect; everything was where I wanted it to be.

It's still got to be tested, but I'll just debug from here and manually correct everything.

Thanks all for the advice. You gave me ideas that helped me to make more sense of things, so that was helpful.

I still don't understand what I was doing wrong, but that's OK; learning is like that sometimes. I do feel like my git knowledge has advanced, and, perhaps more importantly for me, I haven't come away with a "don't go there" attitude, which can sometimes happen.

So, that's all for this. Thanks again for taking the time to respond. That meant a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

The git rebase would actually be:

```
git rebase --onto A F~ I
```

You need to take the parent of `F` as upstream, since a [`rebase --onto`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) rebase all commits *after* the specified upstream commit.

> So when I rebase interactively, the doc that comes up shows each of the commits I want to include (`F` through `I` in my example), and none of the commits I don't want.

That would mean starting from a state where `git log` does *not* show

```
A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---I
```

Because if it did, a git rebase -i A should display in its [todo list](https://A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---I) all commits from A up to the current branch (referencing `I`)
Make sure you are on the right branch before starting said rebase.

Comment: I had to do a bit of googling to figure out what that tilde was for. I hear what you're saying (or at least I think I get where you're coming from), but I couldn't really see how I would get to this "state where git log does not show" you refer to; that is almost the essence of the problem; I was unable to figure out how to get there. 

In any case I found another way, so all is well. Thanks kindly for taking the time to reply. I appreciate it.

Comment: @JimVanM I meant that, if the `rebase -i` was not working, that meant git log was not showing `A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---I`.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, and that will help me in the future (I hope!) :-)

Thanks for taking the time to clarify. It was helpful.